# Olympus OMD EM 5 mark I: camera froze while focusing during macro shot. Wont switch on anymore

Tags: macro, repair, shutter, olympus, olympus-omd

I have an old Olympus OMD EM5 5 Mark I that is in perfect condition. I use it to practise my photography and also to look cool.

I was attempting to take a macro shot; with the target object a bit too far, so I was moving in until it could focus.

The camera then froze with an image in the view finder. No button would work after this. So I decided to switch it off, and back on again.

Nothing, no sound, no lights, nothing. I tried removing the lens and the sd card and attempting to switch it on like that, no luck. I tried inserting and removing and re-inserting the battery, but no luck again. I went home, charged the battery overnight, and inserted in the morning. No luck either.

So I went into a camera store, they inserted a new battery to test, no luck. They inserted my battery into another camera, and that camera switched on, so definitely not the battery.

At this point it is most likely that sending the camera for repair would be a silly idea seeing that it would cost more than the camera is worth. So, is it possible to potentially repair it myself, if anyone has any idea where the problem may be? I mean, if I wreck the camera while trying to fix it there is no problem because its a sitting stone as it stands right now (useless).

Any ideas on what could have broke, if repairable, and how to do so?

Comment: "I have an old Olympus OMD 5 Mark I that *was* in perfect condition." There, I fixed it for you.

Comment: @MichaelC Thanks, I guess ‍♂️

Comment: First thing I would check is if there is a "memory battery", and if it is user (or hacker) replaceable. If the problem is in software at all, disconnecting that could help reset it hard. Does connecting to a PC via USB do anything at all? Next step: Try to get a schematic, verify power rails are within spec, and whether oscillators oscillate.....

Comment: @rackandboneman I have ordered a usb cable online that fits the camera. Am waiting for its arrival, then I will test the connect to computer through usb option and get back to you.

Comment: Olympus cameras use a capacitor, not a battery. Did connecting to a PC help @pnizzle?

Comment: @wilkgr No, that did nothing actually

Comment: Were you storing it with the battery in the camera? If you have, try removing the battery, turning the switch to on and leaving it for a week or two before reinserting the camera. 

(Note- writing this as a comment rather than answer because it's a multistep process to diagnose rather than being able to straight-up say that X is a common cause of failure on these cameras)

Comment: @wilkgr okay, i will try that. I did try leaving the battery out overnight and then trying again next day. A camera shop also tried a new battery and still didn't work. But okay will try leaving it out for a week.

Comment: I understand that. I was mainly suggesting this as it would discharge the internal capacitor. Make sure to turn the switch to "on" after removing the battery.

Comment: Okay will do. Had put it to off.